# skipLocationChange no longer supported?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Getting this error in my angular app when using Router.createUrlTree after updating to latest version:

> Argument of type '{ relativeTo: ActivatedRoute; skipLocationChange: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UrlCreationOptions'.Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'skipLocationChange' does not exist in type 'UrlCreationOptions'.

Does the skipLocationChange property no longer exist? Is there a change that can be made to my code to get equivalent functionality with current stuff?

Comment: It never did anything with createUrlTree, see this issue and the related feature request https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33491

Answer (score 0):

Until Angular <= 7.1 the only options to return from an **AuthGuard** were *boolean*. So we can come up with a classic solution such as:

```
this.router.navigate(['<hidden_url>'], {skipLocationChange: true});
return false;
```

This will navigate without displaying the new URL and, by returning false, will avoid the guarded page to be even rendered.

In case you don't need to hide the URL change, you can simply do:

```
return this.router.createUrlTree(['<url>'])
```